# ruby on rails - ActionView::MissingTemplate in Posts#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Showing `C:/Users/ManU/Desktop/quick_blog/app/views/posts/show.html.erb` where line #3 raised:

```
Missing partial posts/post with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/ManU/Desktop/quick_blog/app/views"
```

Extracted source (around line #2):

```
1. <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
2. <%= render :partial => @post %>
3. <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
4. <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

I'm new to ruby on rails....so don't know how to deal with this problem...please help me regarding this....

Comment: its looking for `C:/Users/ManU/Desktop/quick_blog/app/views/posts/_post.html.erb`

Comment: hi....so what i'm supposed to do..???there is no file _post.html.erb in that directory...if i'll create it manually then...what should be its  content.??

Comment: You can specify the whole path to your partial instead of using `@post`.

Comment: can you please let me know...in detail..actually i'm just 24 hrs old with ruby on rails...dont know much technical terms regarding this...? what is partial..?

Comment: i'm creating a sample form in which we can create,edit,delete a blog and its comment.? the complete project is located in C:\Users\ManU\Desktop\quick_blog....!! What is partial...is it a file or something else..?? then i'll tell you its location..

Comment: create a file _post.html.erb in posts view directory where _post.html.erb contains the view part for a single item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on comments, my first advice is that you have a look at this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html.

Basically, a partial is a view file that you can render in other files. It is useful when you have to use the same piece of code in several files to avoid repetitions.

In your case it seems that you don't actually need it and you could replace the line 2 by the informations you want to display.

But anyway, say that you're writing code in `app/views/posts/show.html.erb` and you want to render the partial `app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb` in it, here is how to do it:

```
<%= render :partial => 'comments/comment' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place the `_post.html.erb` in the `/posts` folder within your views folder.